# Get node id of saved node

Tags: 7, nodes, hooks, forms

I want a function/hook to be called at a point just when my custom node type is saved, I want to get the generated node id in that function, as I have to perform some operations based on nid.

I know one solution is which form alter hook is defined and I give a custom submit function to it and that function is called just when form is submitted, but in that case node is not yet saved at that point so there is no nid.

Comment: Can you specify Drupal version?

Comment: its drupal 7, sorry for late mentioning

Comment: So just google for D7 equivalent of db_last_insert_id

Comment: but the point is where would i call this db_last_insert_id, I need a hook function for that which is called after the node submit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [hook_node_update()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_update/7).

In Drupal 6, you can easily get the last node ID by calling [db_last_insert_id()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database.mysql-common.inc/function/db_last_insert_id/6).