# How do I intercept a press on "Save" and get the nid?

Tags: 7, hooks

I want to get hold of the `nid` of the newly created node whenever a new node or comment is created by a user by pressing "Save" (and only when the user press "Save" - not when the node is created or saved by other means).

I've tried to create a custom submit handler to intercept the save by means of a custom submit handler:

```
$form['#submit'][] = 'mymodule_node_submit';
```

This handler intercepts the press on the "Save" button, but it is invoked too early. The `nid` of the node it is not yet available inside the submit handler.

What is the correct way of getting the `nid` whenever a new node is created by an interactive user?

I know there is a similar question here: [Get node id of saved node](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/36632/get-node-id-of-saved-node) - but the accepted solution (use `hook_node_update()`) is not correct.  `hook_node_update()` will also intercept calls when nodes are created programatically (for instance by the **Feeds** module), when there is no real user involved.

Comment: Don't have the time to code it, but [drupal_static](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_static/7) is a convent way to create a global variable. Using $form['#submit'] set a static variable to be TRUE and then inside of hook_node_update() check that static to see if the node update came from a form submit. Good luck :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read through [`node_form()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.pages.inc/function/node_form/7) you will see that the **Submit** button has its own submit handler:

```
$form['actions']['submit'] = array(
  '#type' => 'submit',
  '#access' => variable_get('node_preview_' . $node->type, DRUPAL_OPTIONAL) != DRUPAL_REQUIRED || (!form_get_errors() && isset($form_state['node_preview'])),
  '#value' => t('Save'),
  '#weight' => 5,
  '#submit' => array('node_form_submit'),
);
```

so you need to add your own submit handler to this

```
function MYMODULE_form_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = 'MYMODULE_node_form_submit';
}
```

Then inside that `$form_state['nid']` or `$form_state['node']` should have what you need.

Answer (score 1):

You can use  `hook_node_submit($node, $form, &$form_state)` and check `$node->op == 'Save'`.

```
This hook is invoked when a node form is submitted with either the "Save" or 
"Preview" button, after form values have been copied to the form state's node 
object, but before the node is saved or previewed.
```

**Update:**
  You can use `hook_node_insert()` itself, if you check the `$node` object it will contain `$node->op` only when creating through UI, it won't be present when creating through code.